# Reorder items in an XFCE4 menu

Tags: xfce, menu

In the Application menu, the "Lock Screen" item is misplaced, does anyone know how to place it just above "Log Out"?

[image: Lock Screen]

Shows "Lock Screen" somewhere in the middle but should appear near the bottom, above "Log Out".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you must locate the corresponding desktop file for the `Lock Screen` entry, this can be done by `grep Lock\ Screen -rl /usr/share/applications/`.

Once you get the name of that file, open up `/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu`, look for lines like this `<Filename>XXXX.desktop</Filename>`, and move it anywhere you like (or just delete that line)

Make sure the xml is valid after your modification, otherwise you get blank menus.

Comment: thanks, it helped clarify the issue. it seems that *.menu file didn't have *.desktop file specified, so i had to write it manually.